# Is digested password safer than salted password?

Tags: encryption, passwords

which scheme is the better one in your opinion?
I know that both are secure but which is better one?

I know that digested passwords are very difficult or even impossible to decrypt.

Thanks for your comments

Comment: This downvote for your spelling.

Comment: @PeterHorvath, what's wrong with the spelling? Yes, there are grammar issues, but those look like common issues for non-expert English writers, and don't affect understandability. There are also semantic errors, but those are also common when people ask about crypto... so, how does down voting for what seems to be nonexistent spelling errors help to improve the question or help people who share the same question?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the purpose of digests and salts.

Digests, also known as hashes, convert the value into a nonreadable mess. The same input always gets the same output.

Salts don't do anything by themselves. A salt is nothing more than a piece of random data. It is used in combination with digests to make the same password hash to something different every time (it's different because "salt + password" is different from "password".) this protects against certain attacks that nonsalted digests don't address.

A salted digest is a more secure way of storing passwords.

Search this site for the terms salt, hash, anddigest to find much more detail on the topic.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer, but can we say that a nonce is a kind of salt?

Comment: You might. However, the terms are used in different contexts, and using the wrong one will (a) not clearly communicate that which you want to communicate, (b) confuse non-experts, and (c) make experts think that you don't really understand the topic. It's best to use the terms as they are intended.